# Strange and different behaviour across netbeans, eclipse and compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have this code in a single file :

```
public class genIntro {
    public static void main(String [] args){
     genTest g = new genTest();
     g.add( 10 );
     System.out.println( g.get() == new Integer(10) ? true:false  );
     Integer in = (Integer) g.get();


    }
}

class genTest(){

        private Object object;

        public void add(Object object) {
            this.object = object;
        }

        public Object get() {
            return object;
        }


}
```

The second class `genTest` has a wrong declaration seen with the brackets `()`.

In Netbeans 6.9.1 the code runs correctly and outputs `false`.

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (Build 201007282301)
Java: 1.6.0_21; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.0-b17
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
Userdir: C:\Users\Name\.netbeans\6.9
```

---

In Eclipse Indigo the code outputs :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at genIntro.main(genIntro.java:4)

Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

---

Then manually compiling via the `javac` command I get :

```
    genIntro.java:12: '{' expected
    class genTest(){
         ^
    1 error
```

This is rather strange, can someone explain why the difference between them? Since it's erroneous why does it compile and run in Netbeans?

Running via `javac genIntro.java`

They all use jre6

*Screenshot :*

[image]

Comment: `g.get() == new Integer(10) ? true:false` seems a little redundant.

Comment: Please include the exact command you're using to compile.

Comment: Are NetBeans and Eclipse using the same compiler as you are on the command line?

Comment: Is the class in a package? What directory are you running `javac` relative to the source code?

Comment: `class genTest() {`, and the compiler sums it up--there can't be parens there, as SteveB says.

Comment: What version of Java are you using in Netbeans, Eclipse and command line? For the record, the code does not compile (as expected) on Eclipse Indigo (Build id: 20110615-0604) with Java 6.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know there can't be any parentheses there, but it ran and still runs on Netbeans 6.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with javac 7 from the command-line and NetBeans 7.1, and it gives the same error as your javac example in both. Are you sure the source is the same in your netbeans version? I can't see how it would compile at all.

Changing the line "class genTest(){" to "class genTest {" allows it to compile, and prints 'false'.

Comment: I can't see why they would compile at all, that's why I am asking this.

Comment: Sorry, I see your point, especially after reading the other answer below. This seems to be connected to 'Compile on Save', which as far as I can figure out uses a special internal compiler rather than the full javac compiler. The internal compiler seems to 'fix' or work round some errors, so you can run code which contains compile errors. There's an interesting FAQ about this on the netbeans wiki, at http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave which goes into more detail about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is odd behaviour indeed. I created a new project in Netbeans (7.0.1) and added your code to it in a `genIntro.java` file. Some observations:

1. The IDE does highlight the syntax error in your code
2. Selecting Run the first time prompts the user that an error exists. You can choose to ignore this permanently, which I did.
3. **If you choose to ignore the syntax error the project appears to build and Run successfully**
4. In the bin folder for the project you can actually find a generated class file for the erroneous source. Reverse compiling this class shows that the syntax error **has been removed**.
5. Back in the IDE, performing a Clean and Build (as opposed to a Run) generates the expected error:

```
Compiling 2 source files to /Users/tuoyo/Work/Data/Netbeans/Misc/build/classes
/Users/tuoyo/Work/Data/Netbeans/Misc/src/misc/genIntro.java:14: '{' expected
class genTest(){
1 error
/Users/tuoyo/Work/Data/Netbeans/Misc/nbproject/build-impl.xml:603: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/tuoyo/Work/Data/Netbeans/Misc/nbproject/build-impl.xml:245: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Since Clean and Build invokes an Ant script behind the scenes I assume it is using the system JDK in console mode, which would jive with your original observations. Left unanswered is the question of how NetBeans is compiling the code when Run is selected - it does appear to be a different execution path.